# Saving location to database using google maps in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="FindCoordinates" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Latitude" HeaderText="Latitude" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Longitude" HeaderText="Longitude" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I get an error when calling: 
`(WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())`

```
protected void FindCoordinates(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + txtLocation.Text + "&sensor=false";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
            dsResult.ReadXml(reader);
            DataTable dtCoordinates = new DataTable();
            dtCoordinates.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("Address", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Latitude",typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("Longitude",typeof(string)) });
            foreach (DataRow row in dsResult.Tables["result"].Rows)
            {
                string geometry_id = dsResult.Tables["geometry"].Select("result_id = " + row["result_id"].ToString())[0]["geometry_id"].ToString();
                DataRow location = dsResult.Tables["location"].Select("geometry_id = " + geometry_id)[0];
                dtCoordinates.Rows.Add(row["result_id"], row["formatted_address"], location["lat"], location["lng"]);
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = dtCoordinates;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the exceptions message.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code.

Comment: Additional information: The remote name could not be resolved: 'maps.googleapis.com'